COUNTER EXAMPLE for Continuity and Monotonic function
Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$
be a function such that

$f(0)=0$
$f(x)=f(−x)$, for all $x$
$f(ax)=a \cdot f(x)$, for all $x$ and positive $a$ 
then $f$ is monotonically increasing and right continuous.


After trying out some examples, I found that no trigonometric functions, polynomials (except constant map to $0$) and exponential functions satisfy the above conditions. Therefore, the only function that satisfies the above condition is the zero function itself. Thus, the constant function is monotonic and continuous. Based on this, the above statement is true, but my instructor says that this statement is false. 
Thanks for the help.


Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

The function cannot be monotonic unless it is constant $0$. If $f(x)\neq 0$ for any $x\neq 0$, then either both $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$ are positive, in which case they are both greater than $f(0)$ but on either side; or both negative, in which case they are both less than $f(0)$ but on either side.

The function $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = |x|$ satisfies the given conditions, but is not monotonically increasing.

But f(-12)=2 & it is not equal to f(-12)=-1*2 , am i correct here?

@V_G The property $f(ax) = a \cdot x$ is only required to hold for positive $a$. For positive $a$, one has $|a| = a$ and hence $f(ax) = |ax| = |a||x| = a|x| = a\cdot f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

thank you very much

Suppose, $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x_1 < 0$. $f(x_1)$ can either be greater than, less than or equal to 0.

If $f(x_1)<0$, according to property 2, $f(x_1)=f(-x_1)<f(0)$ while $x_1<0<-x_1$. This means, going from left to right on the number line, this function rises until $x=0$ and then dips. Which means it is not monotonic.
Same thing for $f(x_1)>0$ but in the opposite order. So, not monotonic.
For, $f(x)=0$, whatever the value of $x$ and $a$, $f(x)=f(-x)=f(ax)=af(x)=f(0)=0$. This is a monotonically increasing (not strict though) and continuous function.

So, yes, $f(x)=0$ appears to be the only function that satisfies the criteria. But,

$f$ is monotonically increasing and right continuous

This statement is not true as it is not true for all $f$. So, the instructor is correct.
